# Is it correct to say that NURBS are not part of Euclidean Geometry?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is it correct to say that NURBS Surfaces are not part of Euclidean Geometry?
I am asking this question in the context of CAD for product design and architecture.
If not, what would be an appropriate way (or category) to distinguish 3D objects made up by discrete lines, planes, arcs, spheres and cylinder segments versus curved "freeform" surfaces that can only be represented exactly with NURBS?

Comment: Where would you classify the conics ? And what about intersection curves which can be high-order ? And what about the torus ?

Comment: In any case, I would not rely on the qualifier Euclidean, which refers more to the fifth postulate.

Comment: Also: what are NURBS?

Comment: @YvesDaoust so a more appropriate distinction would be the order? Where surfaces like cube, spheres  and cylinders are of first order and NURBS surfaces of higher order (=? differential geometry)?

Comment: @Goswin: quadrics are of the second degree. Maybe you can distinguish a group of surfaces by the fact that they have constant curvatures (planes, right cones and cylindres, spheres, toruses), but this forms a rather poor subset, I guess. For mechanical drawings (cogwheels), helixes and involutes are required.

Comment: What is your motivation ? Why exactly do you want to introduce such a classification ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for the help. I see the problems with my definitions. I want to distinguish the geometry of buildings and objects that are designed with "freeform" surfaces and using a CAD system that supports NURBS and intersections on them from buildings and objects that are just polyhedral or with surfaces and lines of constant curvature. (that would be a cylindrical tower or a circular window)

Comment: I don't know a name for that.

Answer (score 0):

The usual term in the CAD industry is "free-form". A free-form shape is one that can not be described by a simple surface like a plane, cylinder, cone, or torus.

This is not a very rigorous classification. What about a surface of revolution that's formed by rotating a spline curve? Is that "free-form" or not?

The term "doubly-curved" is also used sometimes to describe shapes other than planes, cylinders, and cones. But spheres and tori and hyperbolic paraboloids are doubly curved, even though they are not very "free-form".